# Has the Trump administration enforced sanctions related to the Skripal poisonings?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, sanctions

This question is sort of a follow up to [Russian sanctions under Trump](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32782/russian-sanctions-under-trump) ; in short, have Russian sanctions related to the Skripal poisonings actually been implemented/enforced?

Background on this specific event triggering sanctions:

> On 4 March 2018, Sergei Skripal, a former Russian military officer and double agent for the UK's intelligence services, and his daughter Yulia Skripal were poisoned in Salisbury, England, with a Novichok nerve agent

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_of_Sergei_and_Yulia_Skripal

The linked question above mentions sanctions instantiated in August 2018, but asks a timeline for implementation.

On August 1, 2019, Politico writes

> President Donald Trump has signed an executive order imposing sanctions on Russia for its use of chemical weapons in the 2018 attack on the Russian double agent Sergei Skripal and his daughter, according to two U.S. officials.
>   ...
>   But the president, who has been loath to antagonize Russian President Vladimir Putin, dragged his feet on imposing the second round of sanctions.

https://www.politico.com/story/2019/08/01/trump-sanction-russia-chemical-weapons-1444845

So it seems a year later, there are now *two* different sets of sanctions related to Skripal in effect!

But in Jan 2019, NBCNews says

> Nearly three months after deeming Russia in violation of a chemical weapons law, the Trump administration has yet to impose tough new sanctions on Moscow required by the law and triggered by the poisoning last year of former Russian spy Sergei Skripal.

https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/national-security/trump-admin-has-not-imposed-new-sanctions-russia-required-law-n962216

The NBCNews article follows up with the current administration *lifting* some sanctions on Russian companies in Dec 2018, and a related SO question asks  about the [current administration not implementing sanctions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/27681/what-is-the-trump-administrations-legal-basis-for-not-imposing-sanctions-on-rus). That seems to imply that Russian sanctions may not be implemented during the current administration -- however, note that Nov 2018 saw [new Russian sanctions](https://www.politico.com/story/2018/11/08/trump-administration-ups-russia-sanctions-977650)...

I'd really like a detailed understanding of the current administrations relationship to Russian sanctions, but that seems overly broad.

So my question is

Have Russian sanctions related to the Skripal poisonings actually been implemented/enforced?

Answer (score 2):

> Have Russian sanctions related to the Skripal poisonings actually been implemented/enforced?

Officially, yes. Effective August 26, 2019, the sanctions went into effect.

Federal Register, August 26, 2019 [Bureau of International Security and Nonproliferation; Imposition of Additional Sanctions on Russia Under the Chemical and Biological Weapons Control and Warfare Elimination Act of 1991](https://www.federalregister.gov/d/2019-18050). This entry contains a list of sanctions.

---

The Congressional Research Service report [Russia, the Skripal Poisoning, and U.S. Sanctions](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/row/IF10962.pdf), Updated August 14, 2019.

Regarding the second round of sanctions:

> The Administration took its next steps on August 1-2, 2019. On August 1, President Trump issued Executive Order 13883 to require the Secretary of the Treasury to implement measures, “when necessary,” affecting international financing and access to U.S. bank loans. On August 2, Treasury issued a directive (the “CBW Act Directive”) specifying that the latter measures prohibit U.S. banks from “lending non-ruble denominated funds to the Russian sovereign” and participating “in the primary market for non-ruble denominated bonds issued by the Russian sovereign.” According to Treasury, U.S. banks are not prohibited from participating in the secondary market for Russian sovereign debt. Prohibitions do not apply to transactions with Russian state-owned enterprises.
>
> On August 2, the State Department announced the pending imposition of these sanctions, as well as a third: the Department of Commerce would implement a “presumption of denial” policy for export licenses for goods controlled for their dual-use chemical and biological applications.
>
> According to the State Department, the banking and export restrictions enter into effect on or around August 19, 2019, and “could curtail Russia’s access to billions of dollars of bilateral commercial activity with the United States.”

---

While the press in the U.S. did not find it newsworthy; both Tass and Sputnik did.

[Second package of Skripal Case sanctions to come into force on August 26](https://tass.com/world/1074829), 23 AUG [2019].

> The second package of anti-Russian sanctions linked to the so-called ‘Skripal Case’ will become effective from August 26, according to the formal notice of the US State Department posted on Friday in the electronic database of the US Federal Register.
>
> This document will be published on Monday and restrictive measures will apply after that. According to the notification, the decision on restrictions was made as early as on March 29.

[Second Round of US Skripal-Related Anti-Russian Sanctions Comes Into Effect](https://sputniknews.com/europe/201908261076638865-second-round-of-us-skripal-related-anti-russian-sanctions-comes-into-effect/), (updated 09:55 26.08.2019).

> **MOSCOW (Sputnik) - The second round of US sanctions related to the poisoning of former double agent Sergei Skripal took effect on Monday.**
>
> On August 2 [2019], US President Donald Trump signed off on the second round of sanctions against Russia over what described as the poisoning of Skripal in the United Kingdom in 2018 under the Chemical and Biological Weapons Control and Warfare Elimination Act (CBW). The United States claims that Russia is not in compliance with the legislation, but Russia denies the claim.